# Angular JS Binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not sure what is going wrong in the following code - but it doesn't seems working.  can anyone help?

```
<body ng-controller="MyFunction">
        <script>
            function MyFunction($scope) {
                $scope.author = {
                    'name':'Test',
                    'title': 'Mr',
                    'Job': 'SDE'
                }
            }
        </script>
       <h2> {{author.name}} </h2>
       <h2> {{author.title + " " + author.Job}} </h2> 
    </body>
```

Comment: Your script part should be outside ng-controller div

Comment: Check console error and global declaration of controller not supports angular 1.3 + versions.

Comment: Also check if you have given ng-app at the right place.

Comment: @Vineet Thanks for pointing out, the code works fine with Angular Version below 1.3

Comment: Especially if you are new in angular, I highly recommend [using controllerAs.syntax](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#controllers) and not to use $scope for that purpose. Reading the whole styleguide is also generally a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. You are incorrect in structure of angularjs, I don't see the `ng-app` and wrong to declare controller:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyFunction', function($scope) {
  $scope.author = {
    'name': 'Test',
    'title': 'Mr',
    'Job': 'SDE'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyFunction">
  <h2> {{author.name}} </h2>

  <h2> {{author.title + " " + author.Job}} </h2> 
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is several things wrong with your code. You are missing an `ng-app` declaration, you are missing a `module` to use for that declaration and you did not register your `controller` correctly. Your example in a working state:

```js
function authorInfoController() {
  this.author = {
    name: 'Amadeus Smith',
    title: 'Prof.',
    job: 'Super Senior Cloud Advisor Managment Consultant'
  };
}

angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("AuthorInfoCtrl", authorInfoController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AuthorInfoCtrl as info">
  <h2>{{info.author.name}}</h2>
  <h2>{{info.author.title + " " + info.author.job}}</h2>
</div>
```

If you are just learning angular, I recommend doing [a good tutorial](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) and reading [a styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).